# django1.8, I try to get current logined username. in template got work but in view I got failed

Tags: django

I'm quite new in django 1.8.

Now, I'm trying to get current logined username.
I wanna do this. When I post some articles it's author automatically saved to database and displayed in template table.

I already know about
 from django.contrib.auth.models import User 
 and request.user.get_username()

and read lots of articles and QNA about this subject and various tries in two days. But I never find why I only can get username in template but not in view.

I did belows
python manage.py makemigrations BTS(This is name of app)
python manage.py migrate
It works well.

In template, Belows all works well:

```
{{ user.username }}
{{ request.user.username }}
{{ request.user }}
```

In views.py I use get_username method like this. No error but it's not work.:

```
form.username = request.user.get_username()
```

Every other things works fine. But only above one line get anything only empty null value about username, I guess. I need help.

Here is my code. I skip some unnecessary def.

views.py

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from django.utils import timezone
from django.template import RequestContext, loader
from django.shortcuts import redirect
from .models import BTSinput
from .models import BTSreply
from .forms import BTSinputForm
from .forms import BTSreplyForm
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def inputvalidate(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = BTSinputForm(request.POST or None)
        if form.is_valid():
            hold = form.save(commit=False)
            form.created = timezone.now()
            form.updated = timezone.now()
            form.username = request.user.get_username()
            hold.save()
            return redirect('/BTS/list/')
    else:
        form = BTSinputForm()
        return render(request,'BTS/input.html',{'inputform':form})

    return render(request,'BTS/input.html',{'inputform':form})
```

input.html

```
{% block content %}

{% load widget_tweaks %}

<div class="container">
    <div class="starter-template">
     <form method="post" action="/BTS/inputvalidate/">
        {% csrf_token %}
     <div class="form-group">
        <p>subject</p>
        <p>{{inputform.subject|add_class:"form-control"}}</p>
        <p>URLS</p>
        <p>{{inputform.urls|add_class:"form-control"}}</p>        
        <p>text</p>
        <p>{{inputform.text|add_class:"form-control"}}</p>
        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-default">Confirm</button>    
        <a href="/bts/list/"><button type="button" class="btn btn-default">To List</button></a>
     </div>

    </form>
       </div>
    </div>

{% endblock%}
```

models.py

```
class BTSinput(models.Model):
    subject = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank = True)
    text = models.TextField()
    urls = models.URLField(max_length = 100)        
    created = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(default = datetime.datetime.now)
```

forms.py

```
from django import forms
from django.forms import ModelForm
from BTS.models import BTSinput
from BTS.models import BTSreply


# Create your models here.
class BTSinputForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BTSinput
        fields = ['subject','text','urls']


class BTSreplyForm(ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = BTSreply
        fields = ['reply']
```

I checked my setting.py over and over. But... ^^;;;

Here is my setting.py

```
"""
Django settings for mysite project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 1.8.4.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/
"""

# Build paths inside the project like this: os.path.join(BASE_DIR, ...)
import os

BASE_DIR = os.path.dirname(os.path.dirname(os.path.abspath(__file__)))


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = 'n^63(%(va-3wb9l!!2-vg003f)s(3g=%w1*%tv2(8%l)65g&a2'

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = True

ALLOWED_HOSTS = []


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = (
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
    'QNA',
    'BTS',
    'accounts',
    'widget_tweaks',

)

MIDDLEWARE_CLASSES = (
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.SessionAuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
)

ROOT_URLCONF = 'mysite.urls'

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        'BACKEND': 'django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates',
        'DIRS': [],
        'APP_DIRS': True,
        'OPTIONS': {
            'context_processors': [
                'django.template.context_processors.debug',
                'django.template.context_processors.request',
                'django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth',                
                'django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages',
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = 'mysite.wsgi.application'


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3',
        'NAME': os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'db.sqlite3'),
    }
}


# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ko-kr'

TIME_ZONE = 'UTC'

USE_I18N = True

USE_L10N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: `request.user.username` doesn't work?

Comment: Yes, That doesn't work, either. Nonsense.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Once you have called `save` with `commit=False`, you should update the **instance**, not the form.

```
    if form.is_valid():
        hold = form.save(commit=False)
        hold.created = timezone.now()
        hold.updated = timezone.now()
        hold.username = request.user.get_username() # or request.user.username
        hold.save()
```

Comment: IT WORKS! You're right! Why I never thought it before. How to thank you. Save my life. Really I appreciate you.

Comment: I'm reading whole document again, now I stopped :) My reputation below 15. So, I click upvote but not appear, sorry. Thank you so much, again.

Comment: Glad it solved your problem, don't worry about the up vote.